# php auto generate code on the same file

Tags: php

The following code generates a new php file playlist.php which contains the code as in $start $result variable

```
$path = "./files/";
$path2="http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].dirname($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"])."/files/";
//echo $path2;
$folder = opendir($path);
$start="<asx version='3.0'>\n<title>Example ASX playlist</title>";
$Fnm = "./playlist.php";
$inF = fopen($Fnm,"w");
fwrite($inF,$start."\n");
while( $file = readdir($folder) ) {
 if (($file != '.')&&($file != '..')&&($file != 'index.htm')){
 $result="<entry>\n<title>$file</title>\n<ref href='$path2$file'/>\n<param name='image'     value='preview.jpg'/>\n</entry>\n";
     fwrite($inF,$result);
 }
}
fwrite($inF,"</asx>");
closedir($folder);
fclose($inF);
```

I want to generate the same code in the same file which contains this code on a specified line number
is this possible ?

The above php script generates the following code on a new file
http://tinypaste.com/ff242cd6

Comment: You're trying to generate a php file which contains no actual php code? Why?

Comment: I know that I havent include the php code here
this code will be generated below the php tags ?>

Comment: I don't understand this question. Could you carefully explain what you mean by "the same code" and "in the same file"?

Comment: I guess you could append to the file. But I think you should explain exactly why you want to do this, so we can suggest a better solution, if possible.

Comment: @octern Right now, the code writes `$start` and `$result` into a new file. He wants to write that content in the current file, starting on a specific line (appending). I think that's what he/she wants anyway.

Comment: I have index.php which contains this code as mentioned
this script/code generates another code as mentioned in the second code but in a separate php file
I want to generate the same code on the same index.php on a specified line number
for example line 10

Comment: @user1528878 I don't think you can write on a specific line, but I know you can add the content to the end of the file. Would that be okay?

Comment: Ok navnav tell me the way if that works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to append:

```
$path = "./files/";
$path2="http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].dirname($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"])."/files/";
//echo $path2;
$folder = opendir($path);
$start="<asx version='3.0'>\n<title>Example ASX playlist</title>";
$Fnm = "./playlist.php";
// build content
$fileContent=$start.'/n';

while( $file = readdir($folder) ) {
 if (($file != '.')&&($file != '..')&&($file != 'index.htm')){
 $result="<entry>\n<title>$file</title>\n<ref href='$path2$file'/>\n<param name='image'     value='preview.jpg'/>\n</entry>\n";
     //append to content
$fileContent .= $result;
 }
}
     //append to content
$fileContent .= "</asx>";

// append to file and check status
if ( file_put_contents(__FILE__ , $fileContent , FILE_APPEND) === false )
{

echo "failed to put contents in ".__FILE__."<br>";

}
```

That should do it...

EDIT:

Okay, before I get into it, you should first take a look at some basic PHP tutorials which can be found all over the net.

SO, instead of writing the content to the file, just echo it, and add your dynamic stuff while you echo:

```
$title='the title of your playlist';

$start="<asx version='3.0'>\n<title>".$title."</title>/n";

while( $file = readdir($folder) ) {
 if (($file != '.')&&($file != '..')&&($file != 'index.htm')){
 $result="<entry>\n<title>$file</title>\n<ref href='$path2.$file'/>\n<param name='image'     value='preview.jpg'/>\n</entry>\n";
}
}

$endCont = $start.$result."</asx>";

echo $endCont;
```

I created a new variable called `$title`. The value of that will be the title generated in the output. You can do this with other tags too like you've done with `<entry>\n<title>$file</title>`.

Comment: Yes it works but are you sure it will not work for specified line ? because actually I want to dynamically generate some codes between the tags on the same file at some specified line so it is very important

Comment: Right so why don't you just print the content out instead of actually writing it to the file? That way, you could easily add dynamic data in between tags and so on..

Comment: can u give an example of printing the same dynamic codes ? instead of writing

Answer (score 0):

```
echo highlight_file(__FILE__,true);
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.show-source.php

This gets you back the source code of the current file.

Comment: not working
I have index.php which contains this code as mentioned this script/code generates another code as mentioned in the second code but in a separate php file I want to generate the same code on the same index.php on a specified line number for example line 10

Comment: That sounds rather fishy, why do you need to do it? Generally I'd avoid dynamically changing script files unless its really important or thought trough because it can make a lot of problems. The best way as someone said really would be to create a copy of each and manipulate those instead of the original file.

Comment: Actually I want to dynamically generate some codes between the tags on the same file at some specified line
so it is very important